# develop google map program without using google play service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

its necessary to install google play service in devices for using google map otherwise some error occured like

> you have to install google play service

is there any way to use google map for devices that have not google play service installed?

Comment: No, Google player services is required to showing google map in android.

Comment: You don't need to download google-play-services or anything on your device. You should add google-play-services library project to your project, which uses map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally no. The user requires Google Play Services to display a Google Map.

**However**, theres a great abstraction layer for Google Maps on Android. AirBNB has made an open source [AirMapView library](https://github.com/airbnb/AirMapView) that allows you to show a map even if the user does not have Google Play Services by showing them a web view version instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, Google Maps is part of Google Play Services.

If you need maps on devices without Google Play Services — you can use another solutions like Open Street Maps, Yandex.Map, etc

Answer (score 1):

No,

> Google Map API usage is part of service provided by Google Play
>   Services

You have to `install Google Play Service` to use Google Map